# using partials and rendering in rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I am trying to create a website that has groups, each group contains posts, and each post has comments. I have wrote the following code and it is working, yet now I am trying to write this code using partials and then rendering these partials in the groups show view, instead of writing the whole code for posts and comments inside groups show view. I have been trying to do this , but numerous errors shoed up so obviously I have been doing it wrong, Can anyone help me with how to write my code using partials?

here is my code currently:

comments controller:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController



  def new
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.new
  end




  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @group = Group.find(@post.group_id)
    @startup = Startup.find(session[:entity_ID])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.commenter = @startup.name
    @comment.startup_id = session[:entity_ID]
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    end
  end

  def show
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        redirect_to @comment
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
  end

  def destroy
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy
      redirect_to comment_path
  end

  private


  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end
end
```

groups show view:

```
  <p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @group.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @group.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Interest:</strong>
  <%= @group.interest %>
</p>


<h2>Posts</h2>
<% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
<%= @post = post %>
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= post.title %>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Text:</strong>
    <%= post.text %>
  </p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>

  <p>
    <strong><%= comment.commenter %></strong> 
    <%= ":" %>
    <%= comment.comment %>
  </p>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
   <%= form_for([@group,@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

    <p>
      <%= f.text_area :comment %>
    </p>

    <p>
       <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %> 



<h2>Add a post:</h2>
<%= form_for([@group, @group.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(@group) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
```

routes.rb:

```
SprintThrough::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :groups do
     resources :posts, concerns: :likable do
      resources :comments, concerns: :likable
    end
   end
end
```

now I want to create partials for posts and comments and render thos partials in groups Show view. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a `_form_comment.html.erb` and `_form_post.html.erb` files with the codes as below

```
#_form_comment.html.erb

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
   <%= form_for([@group,@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

    <p>
      <%= f.text_area :comment %>
    </p>

    <p>
       <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %> 

#_form_post.html.erb
<h2>Add a post:</h2>
<%= form_for([@group, @group.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And calling those partials in the `groups show page` as below

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @group.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @group.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Interest:</strong>
  <%= @group.interest %>
</p>


<h2>Posts</h2>
<% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
<%= @post = post %>
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= post.title %>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Text:</strong>
    <%= post.text %>
  </p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>

  <p>
    <strong><%= comment.commenter %></strong> 
    <%= ":" %>
    <%= comment.comment %>
  </p>
  <% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'form_post' %>
<%= render :partial => 'form_comment' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(@group) %> | <%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
```

**Note:** These `partial` files should be under `groups views` to make this work.

Comment: what if I need those partials to be under comments or posts and render them in groups, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @user3166918 You can do like this `<%= render :partial => 'posts/form_post' %>` or `<%= render :partial => 'comments/form_post' %>`